# watch command not running on a script

Tags: linux, bash, intervals, watch

I am trying to run a script with watch:

```
watch -n 10 /Users/user/bin/my_script
```

however it does not run the whole script. There are three lines in the script and `watch` stops running after the first one.

When I run the script by itself without the watch command it runs the whole script. Why could this be?

Comment: Perhaps you should include the script, since it contains only three relevant lines.

Comment: If your script is a bash script, you might want to try: watch -n 10 bash /Users/user/bin/my_script

Comment: Do you reference other script files inside /Users/user/bin/my_script ?

Comment: @ShellFish what do you mean include the script?

Comment: @Ma'moonAl-Akash yes' it is a bash script so I tried adding bash command on the line but it still stops after the first one in the script.

Comment: Add the content of my_script to the question.